# How to hide axis lines with CSS?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

How do I hide my axis lines with CSS? Shouldn't this work?

```
<mx:Style>
  @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

  mx|ColumnChart {
    horizontalAxisStyleName: myAxisStyles;
    verticalAxisStyleName: myAxisStyles;
  }
  .myAxisStyles { showLine: false; }
</mx:Style>
```

I also tried display: none.

Prior to this I used:

```
<mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
  <mx:AxisRenderer showLine="false" axis="{someName.horizontalAxis}" />
</mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
<mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
  <mx:AxisRenderer showLine="false" axis="{someName.verticalAxis}" />
</mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
```

But it produced some annoying warnings:

```
Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "horizontalAxis".
Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "verticalAxis".
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flex 4.5 ,setting showLine:false thru CSS didn't work for me too. Later I found that the CartesianCharts takes an array not a string as an input for horizontalAxisStyleNames.Note it is not **horizontalAxisStyleName**, it is **horizontalAxisStyleName*s***.I did a quick work around and the showLine property was applied to the chart. It may not seem meaningful, but I had no other choice and this works like a charm!

Code for your reference:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    mx|ColumnChart {
        horizontalAxisStyleNames:myAxisStyles,myAxisStyles;
    }

    .myAxisStyles {
        showLine:false;
    }

</fx:Style>
```

Comment: Kinda ugly hack though. Messes up my tick marks too. Reverting back to the old method.